# Create plugin with form in post and submit it to specific form

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, forms

I need to write plugin which add form at the end of specific posts with submit button. It is clear for me. Next after click submit I need to submit form to my own form from plugin and show more inputs for user. After filling the form I want to save data to db.

I know how to do all the things, but how can I submit my form included in post to other specific URL?

Thanks for all advices.

Comment: Forms have an attribute `action` where you should put the url of the page that process form. In your case that url should be the permalink of the *other* post that you can retrieve using `get_permalink`

Comment: I haven;'t tried anything, because I have no idea how to do this. @G.M. Ok, but I don't want to create other post, I want to submit form to my plugin. Is there any posibility to get link do plugin function?